# How can I subtract a value from a column B based upon a string value of column A

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create another column (novig_new) which contains the value of the Pinnacle bookmaker's novig_prob subtracted from the other bookmakers for each team.  Here is my tibble:

[image: Bookmaker odds]

This is what I am looking to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput` to show example data instead of images

Comment: Something like `data %>% group_by(team) %>% mutate(novig_prob = novig_prob[bookmaker == "Pinnacle"] - novig_prob) %>% ungroup()`. If that doesn’t work, please share your data in copy-pasteable form using `dput(data)`. Also have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we may need

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(team) %>%
   mutate(novig_new = novig_prob - novig_prob[match("Pinnacle", bookmaker)]) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun.  This is useful and super easy solution.

Comment: @AaronMorris in your dput, you have only values 'Pinnacle' in the bookmaker